# how to detect html element in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-daterangepicker

How can I detect an element from the HTML when there is no such element, here is a range picker I want to detect the custom range item in typescript

[image]

**this is the HTML code**

```
                  <form action="" id="dates">
              <input   [class.show-calend]="showCalendar"  readonly="readonly"  id="range-picker" type="text" class="form-control inspection_date"
                     name="dateRange" placeholder="Add date"
                     [formControl]="dateRange" style="cursor: pointer"
                     daterangepicker (selectionDone)="onSelectionDone($event)"   [options]="rangeOptions" (cancelDaterangepicker)="cancel($event)" (selected)="selectedDate($event)"  (ngModelChange)="ngModelChange($event)" />
              </form>
```

**this is the HTML code which is visible only when I open the dev panel on a browser**

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get "Custom Range " element something like `document.getElement` in Typescript ?

Comment: you can get an element using `document.getElement*` if it's visible in the dev panel.

Comment: Are you expecting something like this - `const htmlEle = document.querySelector('.ranges ul li[data-range-key="Custom Range"]') as HTMLElement;`

Comment: @PiyushJain in the console gives null

Comment: you have to run it once your DOM is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way

```
elementLi:any
this.elementLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[7];
```